# Why does my mac lose internet when I connect my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, wifi, macos, internet

I'm using wifi for internet access, but when I connect my iPhone via lightning cable all my internet activity comes back as "destination unreachable" or similar errors.

How do I troubleshoot and correct this issue so the mac stays online using the wifi when I connect my iphone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Goto `Settings -> Networks` and check that your **connected** iPhone is not first on the list.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue.  For those seeking out this problem later, click the gear icon below the list and choose "Set Service Order" to move items on the list so the iPhone is below wifi.

Comment: I don't have iPhone USB when connecting my iPhone but my internet is still lost

Comment: @VitaliiKorsakov, not sure if you have your internet through iPhone (in which case it should present somehow in the list), but just in case, check your DNS settings then.